# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:18)

Tags: reactjs

I am experiencing an error.

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:18)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
function truncate(string, n) {
     return string?.length > n ? string.substr(0, n - 1) + '...' : string;
}
```

Comment: Unexpected tokens usually appear when the variable is not properly endoded, decoded or maybe not even there.  
You should upload a bit more of the code or use console.log({string}) to see what you are handling.  
In any way, you should post a bit more of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.